# Problem streaming Excel file with images, Flask, Gcloud Storage, Openpyxl, doesn't saves file with all the images

Tags: python, flask, io, openpyxl, gcloud

if anybody can help me, please.

I am trying to work with an excel (xlsx) file that has images. The file is in a Gcloud storage Bucket that is downloaded from the main.py (flask) and is send to a python function in another file (createReport.py) the file is read, change and all functions well, but when I save it, the file doesn´t include the images from the template file.

This is han example of the code:

```
@app.route('/', methods= ['GET', 'POST'])
def root():
  wb = io.BytesIO()
  blob = bucket.blob(pathReportfile)
  blob.download_to_file(wb)

  wb = create(wb)

  blob = bucket.blob(path)
  blob.upload_from_string(wb.getvalue())
  wb.close

  return render_template('index.html')

def create(wb):
  wbReport = openpyxl.load_workbook(wb, read_only=False)
  .
  #makes changes to the file only data
  .
  wb = io.BytesIO()
  wbInforme.save(wb)
  wbInforme.close

  return wb
```

The file is downloaded directly from the public storage bucket "-https:[www.google.com/...excelprojects..."](http://www.google.com/...excelprojects...%22)

The image in the left is the template and the image on the right is the downloaded file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8hfl.png)

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps: https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1427